# Accessing asp page from Java

Tags: httpurlconnection

I am trying to access website http://www.billing.mppkvvcl.org/wzltbill.asp. On this page I need to choose "Service Number" and provide service number in text box.

In the background it executes
form id="ActionForm" name="LTViewFrm" class="atnbill" method="post" action="wzltatnpay.asp" onsubmit="return yav.performCheck('LTViewFrm',LTViewArray,'classic');"

I am trying to use HttpURLConnection to do this but I am having some problem in accessing asp class and asp method.

Please let me know if someone has any idea to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) library, as it provides feature on form submission. Check out this [example code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/FormLoginDemo.java?revision=604567&view=markup) on how to submit form using the library.